# Is Forever Ω actually The Biologist?

Tags: character-similarity, ayreon

In the Ayreon chronology, the Forever are

> actually from Planet Alpha, where a select few individuals escape the destruction of their homeworld to Planet Y, where they become the Forever. (this being the plot of *The Source*)

The Forever (as the name implies) are effectively immortal and can stay around, well, forever. However, this begs the question if anyone from *01011001* is a recurring character from The Source.

Namely, though, Floor Jansen (playing both Forever Ω in *01011001* and The Biologist in *The Source*) appears in both albums. Is this an intentional part of the story or did Lucassen just decide to bring Floor back for another album? Has this ever been addressed by Lucassen or any of Ayreon's material?